# How to handle toggle in Cypress?

Tags: toggle, cypress

*If toggle is enabled - need to fill up a form which shows up only after enable. If toggle is disabled - no need to look for form as it is hidden.

I want to check whether the toggle is initially disabled or not and carry out next steps accordingly. If it is disabled, then 1st - I want to enable it and fill forms and hit Save, 2nd - leave it as it is and hit Skip.
Similarly, if the toggle is initially enabled, I want to 1st - disable it and hit Skip, 2nd - leave it as it is, fill form fields and hit Save.
What can I do in this situation?

*Filling up form and Skip/Save is not a problem.

Cypress code for Disable:

```
it('Disable', function () {
    cy.get('input[aria-label="primary checkbox"]').then(($ele) => {
        if ($ele.is(':checked')) {
            $ele.check() // to disable if enabled
            
            cy.wait(1000)
            cy.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[2]/button')
            .click() // Skip
            
        } else {
            cy.wait(1000)cy.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/form/div[2]/button/span[1]')
                .click() // Skip
        }
    })
})
```

Cypress code for Enable:

```
it('Enable', function () {        
    cy.get('input[aria-label="primary checkbox"]').then(($ele) => {
        if ($ele.is(':checked')) {
            cy.wait(1000)
            cy.get('form').within(($form) => {
                cy.get('input').first().clear().type(8)
                cy.get('input').eq(1).clear().type(4)
                cy.get('input').last().clear().type(4)
            })
            cy.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/form/div[2]/button/span[1]')
            .click() // Save
        } else {
            $ele.check() // to enable if disabled
            
            cy.wait(1000)
            cy.get('form').within(($form) => {
                cy.get('input').first().clear().type(8)
                cy.get('input').eq(1).clear().type(4)
                cy.get('input').last().clear().type(4)
            })cy.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[2]/button')
            .click() // Save
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<span class="MuiSwitch-root jss984">
 <span class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root jss638 MuiSwitch-switchBase 
 MuiSwitch-colorPrimary" aria-disabled="false">
   <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
       <input class="jss641 MuiSwitch-input" name="checkedB" type="checkbox" 
       aria-label="primary checkbox" value="">
       <span class="MuiSwitch-thumb"></span>
   </span>
   <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
 </span><span class="MuiSwitch-track"></span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the demo page, [material-ui - switches](https://material-ui.com/components/switches/)

- right-click on one of the switches
- select "inspect"
- in the elements pane, right-click the input and select "Store as global variable"
- in the console pane, shows "temp1"
- enter "temp1.click()"
- it changes!

Saves all the guess-work!

So, on that page to target the second toggle,

```js
cy.get('span.MuiSwitch-root')
  .eq(1)
  .find('input')
  .click();
```

Note: It's a toggle so `click()` will go from on to off and from off to on.

Each test should be written such that you **know** the state of the form. The idea of conditional testing is not good - I mean, when you navigate to the page you don't get a random toggle state. Most likely it starts off with the form hidden.

You tests would be

- when the page opens, test that the form is hidden
- when the user clicks the toggle, test that the form becomes unhidden

etc.

Comment: That's not the question. The question is how to enable or disable a toggle. He doesn't need to enable a second toggle he needs to know if the toggle is enabled to disable it and if it is disabled to leave it alone.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [:checked](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) in Jquery, You can do something like this:

```
cy.get('input[aria-label="primary checkbox"]').then(($ele) => {
  if ($ele.is(':checked')) {
    return
  } else {
    cy.wrap($ele).click()
  }
})
```

Comment: It did not completely work. Let me edit my question.

Comment: When enabled, it said check is not a function.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Can you please try now.

Comment: it worked for the first time. But did not the next. Toggle did not get enabled.

Comment: Which part is not working `($ele.is(':checked')` or `cy.wrap($ele).check()` ? the first validates if your checkbox is checked and the second checks your checkbox.

Comment: the second one.

Comment: how about if you just use `cy.wrap($ele).click()` ?